# Changing location of specific nodes in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a simple Tikz diagram, but for some reason I dont seem to be able to modify the location of certain nodes, they are always at (0,0). Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!20] (0,0) rectangle ++(4.8,5);
\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!20] (4.8,5) -- (4.9,4.8)--(4.9,-0.1)--(4.8,0);
\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!20] (0,0) -- (0.1,-0.1)--(4.9,-0.1)--(4.8,0);

\pgfmathsetseed{3}

%% Both of the following are always at (0,0)
\draw plot [smooth cycle, samples=8,domain={1:8}] (\x*360/8+2*rnd:0.1cm+0.1cm*rnd) node at (4,3) {}; 
\node [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw, minimum height=5, minimum width=4,fill=NavyBlue]{} (4.6,4.7);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They are not but very close because of your choice `(\x*360/8+2*rnd:0.1cm+0.1cm*rnd) `. The `at (4,3)` has no effect, so does `(4.6,4.7)` because there is no `at` before. Could you perhaps describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: @marmot the second one, with the at, errors. What I want to achieve is to put them in the said location?  The big square is approximately 5x5, basically I want to be able to specify their location in the same coordinate system of the first square, I assume.

Comment: The cylinder node does not give an error if you use Ti*k*Z syntax, `\node at (4.6,4.7) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw, minimum height=5, minimum width=4,fill=NavyBlue]{};`. The command above is a plot. Do you want to spread out the plot over the full plane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!20] (0,0) rectangle ++(4.8,5);
\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!20] (4.8,5) -- (4.9,4.8)--(4.9,-0.1)--(4.8,0);
\draw[draw=black,fill=gray!20] (0,0) -- (0.1,-0.1)--(4.9,-0.1)--(4.8,0);

\pgfmathsetseed{3}

%% Both of the following are always at (0,0)
\draw[shift={(2.4,2.5)}] plot [smooth cycle, samples=8,domain={1:8},variable=\x] 
(\x*360/8+2*rnd:1cm+1cm*rnd); 
\node at (4.6,4.7) [cylinder, shape border rotate=90, draw, minimum height=5, minimum width=4,fill=NavyBlue]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]